# keeping a default value for parameters form one report to another SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

```
SELECT TOP (100) User_ID ,
Amount,date, contact_Det details FROM Client
```

hi i have a table report that displays data according to `user_ID`(parameter),
one of the rows in the table a drill through function, i want to keep the User_ID form this report when i go to the other report via the drill through.when i run the report it displays info for certain client, to select a different client i filter with the `User_ID`.

say i want contact details for `USER_ID` 3
i should click on the drill through for `Contzct_Det` and it will take me to ContactReport and display user contact where the default value is  `USER_ID` 3

Comment: Any tutorial on drill through in SSRS will tell you how to pass a parameter to the target report.  What have you tried, and in what way did it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should pass the parameter value to the target report(another report as per you written). In target report use that parameter value in filter(where clause in dataset) so data should be filter as per passing parameter.